# Loader is not showing in case of a request that has not turned out an response yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, http, axios

I am building a react cryptocurrency project and trying to find out why the loader does not show up at while waiting for an api response. So I have an onClick function that calls an api.

```
 const handleShowSecondScreen = () => {
    executeTransaction(price)
      .then((res) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        if (!res.status) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else if (res.status === 'OK') {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setSuccessfulTransactionInfo(res);
        } else if (res.status === 'FAILED') {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setWidgetView(SCREEN_VIEWS.FAILED);
        }
      });
  };
```

So what is supposed to happen is that once I click on the button, the loader is supposed to show up, until after there is a response from the api. However, when I click the button, no loader shows up, and it waits for the response. Not sure what is happening here. Let me know if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: You should put your first `setIsLoading(true);` outside the `executeTransaction(price)
      .then()`. For your code above, your loader shows after the API fetch is finished instead of shows after button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the loader before the method call.

```
 const handleShowSecondScreen = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    executeTransaction(price)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.status) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else if (res.status === 'OK') {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setSuccessfulTransactionInfo(res);
        } else if (res.status === 'FAILED') {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setWidgetView(SCREEN_VIEWS.FAILED);
        }
      });
  };
```

In your case, you could refactor the code into something like this.

```
const handleShowSecondScreen = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    executeTransaction(price)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.status) {
          return
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
        if (res.status === 'OK') {
          setSuccessfulTransactionInfo(res);
        } else if (res.status === 'FAILED') {
          setWidgetView(SCREEN_VIEWS.FAILED);
        }
      });
  };
```